# Functions to give quantile and probability for multinomial distribution in R

Tags: r, function, probability

I want to be able to compute the quantile and probability for multinomial outcomes in R. R has similar function for other distributions such as `qnorm()`, and `pnorm()`. Following the same naming scheme, I want `qmultinom()` and `pmultinom()` since R already has `rmultinom()` and `dmultinom()`. I searched on the Internet but could not find them.

As for `pmultinom()`, suppose Y is an outcome (a vector), I want to know the proportion of all possible multinomial outcomes that result in `dmultinom(Y,size,prob)` or lower.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with 'quantile' in a multivariate setting? As far as I'm aware, there is no straightforward generalization of the quantile function from a one-dimensional space to a d-dimensional space, due to the lack of a natural ordering in higher dimensional spaces.

Comment: I think there are probably multiple output for a particular quantile and perhaps they are not exact (i.e., outcomes for a particular exact quantile do not exist). If it is more objectively clear, 'pmultinom()' is also helpful, although it may have a similar problem.

Comment: I recognize how I defined pmultinom is not consistent with other p-dist functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at my package, [pmultinom](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pmultinom/index.html).

It does not match your definition of taking a probability as input, but it is analogous to, for example, pbinom. For example, asking the probability that a binomial outcome is <= 5:

```
pbinom(5, 10, .5)
# [1] 0.6230469
> pmultinom(upper=c(5,Inf), size=10, probs=c(.5, .5), method="exact")
# [1] 0.6230469
```

And of course you can instead ask whether all three cells in a multinomial distribution will have counts <= 5:

```
pmultinom(upper=c(5,5,5), size=10, probs=c(1/2, 1/4, 1/4), method="exact")
# [1] 0.5835915
```

There's also [another pmultinom library on Github](https://github.com/fennerm/pmultinom). It looks like we both based it on the same reference, but I implemented the suggestion for an exact calculation, whereas the author of this package implemented the approximate calculation, so it may be faster.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried `logspline` package?

```
library(log spline)
b <- rmultinom(10000, size = 100, prob = c(0.1,0.5,0.8))
hist(b, 100)
a <- logspline(b)
plot(a)
qlogspline(.2,a)
```